# gi.repository not found using python with anaconda

Tags: python, path, anaconda, linux-mint

I have a problem with running gi.repository using anaconda. When I run python it runs by default from:

```
~/anaconda2/bin/python
```

and then I have an error that gi.repository module doesn't exist. If I run python from standard path (without anaconda):

```
/usr/bin/python
```

everything is fine. Can anyone help me with making it work when using anaconda?

Comment: have you find a solution?